# MYSQL Query to retrieve data on single table to get the Max Date and Max Amount, considering multiple field on the condition

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max

I'm working on a system report that can retrieve data of the last purchased cost of an item based on a certain date and considering last purchase cost on different location of an item.

This query work perfectly fine on MSSQL but on MySQL when I run same queries it hangs due to issue on subquery with where condition inline, see the queries below. I look some issue about MySQL with those type of queries and their suggestion is to re-code the queries, I tried to re-code it with SUBQUERY with WHERE condition but it I can't get the right.

```
SELECT
     t1.Location
    ,t1.Item
    ,MAX(t1.Cost) as Cost
    ,t1.Date
FROM TABLE as t1
WHERE t1.Date =
(
    SELECT
        MAX(t2.DATE)
    FROM TABLE as t2
    WHERE t1.Location = t2.Location 
    AND t1.Item = t2.Item 
    AND t2.DATE <= 'CERTAIN DATE'
)
GROUP BY t1.Location, t1.Item, t1.Date;
```

Please see image for sample data and expected result:

[Sample Table and Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwHiU.png)

Can somebody help me to re-code the queries? because when I used same code on MySQL and with a large number data to be read and retrieve, the queries just hang-up for a couple of hours.

Btw, my MySQL server is 5.6

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(LOCATION,ITEM,COST,DATE)AS
(
  SELECT 'LOCATION 1','ITEM 1',100,CAST('20210201'AS DATE)UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LOCATION 1','ITEM 1',105,'20210215'UNION ALL
  SELECT  'LOCATION 1','ITEM 1',103,'20210219'UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LOCATION 2','ITEM 1',107,'20210203'UNION  ALL
  SELECT 'LOCATION 2','ITEM 1',105,'20210215'UNION ALL
  SELECT 'LOCATION 2','ITEM 1',100,'20210213'
)
SELECT X.LOCATION,X.ITEM,X.COST,X.DATE
FROM
 (
   SELECT C.LOCATION,C.ITEM,C.COST,C.DATE,
   ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY C.LOCATION ORDER BY C.DATE DESC)AS XCOL
   FROM CTE AS C
)AS X WHERE X.XCOL=1
```

CTE is a yours test data representation